# VAO deleting causes strange memory problems

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-leaks

I have a render cycle looking like this: import model -> draw it (some frames...) -> delete it. To draw the model I'm using vao/vbo/ebo.

Now, in a delete stage with this code:

`glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);`

while profiling in Xcode Allocation instrument, I get this[image]

whereas if the code is written like:

`glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);`

suddenly it shows:

[image]

Why is this happening? I change nothing but the order of `glDeleteVAO` / `glDeleteBuffers` and getting this strange 'memory leaks'. All these 3 lines of code are placed in the dctor and are not distributed across the app.

Also, `glIsBuffer()` after deleting vbo, vao, ebo returns 0 in all these cases on all buffers.

using opengl 4.1 on os x el capitan

Comment: I believe OpenGL won't actually delete something until everything using it is unbound and deleted. Have you tried explicitly unbinding all of those first (by binding the respective parts to `0`)? It could also decide to clean it up at its own discretion, I suspect. I don't recall the standard being too explicit.

Comment: @WilliamKappler I have already unbound all the buffers. OpenGL actually frees memory after the reference count reaches zero. But how changing calls order helps that?

Comment: Well, if it actually _did_ that, call order shouldn't change the behavior. But OpenGL implementations are notoriously touchy. You might want to run the test on other systems (or just other drivers) and see if the results differ.

Comment: @ibe: What does " I have already unbound all the buffers" exactly mean? If the VAO (which isn't a buffer) is still bound, the behavior is totally understandable. But even if not, the GL implementation is free to delay the deallocation basically indefinitely, and it may re-use the resources later on instead of giving it back to the OS.

Comment: @derhass The VAO is automatically unbound when `glDeleteVertexArrays()` is called for it. In any case, a more conclusive test here would be to execute the code sequence repeatedly, and see if the memory usage keeps increasing. If it does, it's probably a bug in the OpenGL implementation.